# Where is the error in this proof by induction?

Tags: solution-verification, induction

My assertion is that for any positive integer $n$, the following statement holds true: $a^{n-1} = 1$. The following is a preliminary proof by induction on the positive integer $n$: If $n = 1$ then $a^{n-1} = a^0 = 1$ and So the statement is correct in this case. Now take $n > 1$ and suppose , as an induction hypothesis, that $a^{k-1} = 1$ when $k = n-1, n-2, ...,1$. We then have: $a^{n-1} = a^{n-2}  a^{1} = a^{n-2}  \frac{a^{n-2}}{a^{n-3}}  = 1 * \frac{1}{1} = 1$. Therefore, we have established that the statement holds true for every positive integer $n$. At what point during the induction process was the mistake made?

Comment: If $n=2$ then $a^{n-3}$ makes no sense (or at least you have assumed nothing about it in your inductive step).

Comment: As @Randall mentioned, $2 - 3 \notin \mathbb{Z}^+$, so your inductive step does not follow.

Comment: Since $a^1 \neq a^0$ for all integers a, then it is obviously false. I’d say your error is in how you setup your base case.

Comment: @RyanPierceWilliams $1^1$ *is* equal to $1^0$ (both are $1$).

Comment: @K.Jiang Note I said that it is not the case for ALL integers (not some). Albeit upon re-reading my comment I could have stated it better.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you have to use $a^{n-2}$ and $a^{n-3}$ in the last step, which are for $n=2,3$ not covered by proving the statement for $n=1$. This means that  before using the induction hypothesis, you would have to prove the statement for all of $n=1,2,3$, which of course is not possible (since the statement is wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake

You take $k = n - 2$
Now you assume for $a^{n-2}$=1
And then you prove for whenever $a^{n-2}=1$, then
$a^{n-1}=1$

But how do you assume $a^{n-3}=1$.
That is a wrong assumption.
Because when n=1, you show your statement is correct. When n=2, n-2=0 but n-3=-1, so does the statement hold true?
You have only the assumption that P(k) is true while proving P(k+1) is true and no other assumption.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial